# Having trouble using pipeline in shell

Tags: c, linux, shell, process, pipeline

I'm writing a basic shell in c .
Now it can execute single-process commands , handling input and output redirection and execute command in background.
The problem is that , when I tried to use pipeline,it can execute command correctly ,but after that the shell stop typing prompt and stop receiving command.

Such as: cat a.txt | grep abc

Result:
$abc
(empty line and stop reacting)

And whatever I type in the shell won't react to it.
I guess there's something wrong with std_input redirection or there's a process that didn't end.

Here's the code to launch command.

```
void lsh_launch(char **args)
{
int pid=fork();
if (pid== 0)  //children
{
    if(pipe_bool==0)
    {

        if(redir_in_bool==1 && redir_out_bool==1) //redirect input and output
        {
            close(STD_INPUT); 
            int re_input=open(redir_in_adr,O_RDONLY); //open file
            dup(re_input); //redirect std input
            close(STD_OUTPUT);
            int re_output=open(redir_out_adr,O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO);
            dup(re_output);//redirect std output
            execvp(args[0],args);

        }
        else if(redir_in_bool==1 && redir_out_bool==0) //redirect input
        {
            close(STD_INPUT);
            int re_input=open(redir_in_adr,O_RDONLY);
            dup(re_input);
            execvp(args[0],args);
        }
        else if(redir_out_bool==1 && redir_in_bool==0) //redirect output
        {
            close(STD_OUTPUT);
            int re_output=open(redir_out_adr,O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO);
            dup(re_output);
            execvp(args[0],args);
        }
        else   //normal command
        {
            execvp(args[0],args);
        }
    }
    else  //pipeline
    {
        char* line2 = lsh_read_line();
        char** args2 = lsh_split_line(line2);
        pipeCommand(args,args2);
        free(line2);
        free(args2);
    }

} 
else  //parent
{
        if(background_bool!=1 )
        {
            waitpid(pid, NULL, 0); 
        }
}
return ;
}
```

Pipeline code:

```
#define STD_INPUT  0
#define STD_OUTPUT 1
void pipeCommand(char **parameter1,char **parameter2)
{
int pipefd[2];
pipe(pipefd);

if(fork())                      //parent process execute second command 
{
    close(pipefd[1]);
    dup2(pipefd[0],STDIN_FILENO);
    close(pipefd[0]);
    execvp(parameter2[0],parameter2);
}
else                            //child process execute first command
{
    close(pipefd[0]);
    dup2(pipefd[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(pipefd[1]);
    execvp(parameter1[0],parameter1);
}
}
```

And the other code
http://ideone.com/XEuBVA

Comment: What output do you see when you run the command `echo first command | echo second command` ?

Comment: Input

$echo a | echo b

 Output: 

b\n b\n 

$$

Comment: Why is there two 'b' ?
And now i can type in command..
But "cat a.txt | grep abc" still doesn't work

Comment: When the user types a pipe command to your shell, after it is executed,  the `lsh_launch` function is being called again to run the second command again. The reason it looks like the shell has stopped reacting after you type `cat a.txt | grep abc` is that another `grep abc` command is running, and it is reading from the terminal.

Comment: I found where's the problem.
I keep reading input untill there is a ' | ',then i stop reading and return the char buffer,and the second command(haven't read yet)was read in the main function,so it execute the second command two time.

Comment: Now i use fgets instead of getchar,and it work just fine.
Thank you very much!